# What is a good C# PDF library for form-heavy webapp?

Tags: c#, pdf, forms

I am in need of recommendations for a good C# .NET PDF library for a web application that will make heavy use of PDF forms. First, the library needs to have commercial licensing. Also, it needs to have robust features for merging data into PDF forms, extracting data, flattening form fields that have data, etc. If the library includes barcoding, that'd be great.

Comment: Our product PDFOne .NET can [create, edit, fill, and flatten PDF forms](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=106&t=How_to_Create_and_Fill_PDF_Forms_in_NET). You can also [use barcode fonts in PDF form fields](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=183&t=Creating_User-Friendly_Barcode_PDF_Form_Fields_In_NET).

Answer (score 1):

[iTextSharp](http://www.itextsoftware.com/) is fairly popular around here.  It is available under AGPL and commercial licenses (with source of course).

It'll do just about anything that can be done with AcroForms-based PDF forms (including flattening), and can get/set values with LiveCycle Designer forms.  It also supports the following symbologies:

- Codabar
- Code 39 (and variants)
- Code 128
- DataMatrix (2d)
- EAN (8 & 13)
- Interleaved 2 of 5
- PDF417 (2d)
- Postnet
- UPCA and UPCE

Huh.  I thought it supported code 93, but I don't see anything in the code here to back that up.

The book iText In Action 2nd Edition is pretty good.  Commercial support is available (included with a commercial license), and the help here and on their mailing list is quite good.

Disclaimer: iTextSoftware pays me from time to time for services rendered.  Whether or not you use decide to use iText will not affect that amount.